# java - get mouse events outside of a component

Tags: java, mouse, location, frame, drag

i'm having the same issue as the person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757078/events-for-window-dragging-in-java), in that i need to track a frame location while it is being dragged on OS X. The question had not been resolved there, so:

how do i tell a frame that a mouse down event happened on its (OS-native) title bar or, more generally, that a mouse down event happened somewhere on the screen?

Comment: added link to native lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since java 1.5

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class Mouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while ( true ) {
            System.out.println( MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() );
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Native keyboard mouse hook

http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90

Comment: this gives the absolute location of the pointer on screen, but no button events, so it's kind of half the deal...

Comment: What you are looking for is indeed requiring JNI

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Java, you can never tell that a mouse down event happened on its (OS-native) title bar, or for that case any event outside you application window(excluding title bars).

It's important understand that as a programmer in AWT/Swing your context and realm and power lies only within the application window. 
Best shot is to use JNI.